# How I Can Return my base Value From ComputeHash string? C#

Tags: hash

this is my Code

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myuser= "Admin";
        string mypass= "123";
        SHA256Managed managed = new SHA256Managed();
        this.passwordHashTextBox.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(managed.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myuser.ToLower() + mypass)));
    }
```

this code Return for me this string="JAvlGPq9JyTdtvBO6x2llnRI1+gxwIyPqCKAn3THIKk="
Now I'l  want Get myuser And mypass From this code 
Help me PL ..
Thanks everyone

Comment: Hashes tend to be one direction only, as EG. it is not practical for a password to be able to get back from its hash...

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** You can't (unless you have lot of computational power and/or time). The Base64 transformation can easily be reverted, but the hash part is a one way transformation.

It's a very usefull property when there's the need to prove someone you know something (let's call it `X`) without actually having to show him `X`, assuming he known what `hash(X)` looks like, you can show him `hash(X)` instead. This works because it's almost impossible to find a `Y` so that `hash(Y)==hash(X)`. This is just one use case, there are more.

It's not absolutly clear what you are trying to accomplish with that code, but I suggest you to read some about hash functions before continuing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function